# Display two animations at the same time with Manim

Tags: python-3.x, manim

I am trying to run two animations at the same time, for example: a dot falling between two letters as those letters make space in between them.
Any advice on how to do so?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To apply two transformations at the same time, you can do `self.play(Transformation1, Transformation2)`. This way, since the two Transformations are in the same play statement, they will run simultaneously.